# how can I remotely check if a proxy is NTLM enabled

Tags: proxy, ntlm

I have no administrative access to the proxy host.  But I want to know remotely whether the proxy is NTLM enabled and what version. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

please have a look at this tool:
http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/
When you download it (windows version) you'll find inside the zip file a PDF Manual.
Open it and have a look at -M option (please find hereafter the option description for your convenience):

> -M 
>   Run magic NTLM dialect detection. In this mode, cntlm tries some known working presets
>   against your proxy. Probe requests are made for the specified testurl, with the strongest hashes
>   going first. When finished, settings for the most secure setup are printed. Although the detection
>   will tell you which and how to use Auth, Flags and password-hash options, you have to configure
>   at least your credentials and proxy address first. You can use -I to enter your password interactively.

hope this help
cheers
UnknowNTLM